# Are all PDA equivalent to two-state-PDA?

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

We know algorithm to convert each PDA in the underlying grammar that generates the language the PDA recognize.
But we have also the algorithm for creating a two state pda from a grammar. 
This algorithm use the first state for all the computation, with rules based on the stack and the input symbol, and when the stack is empty goes to a final state.
This  means that, for all the generic PDAs we can create a minimal PDA with only two states (and a lot of rules for the first state).
Am I right?

Comment: It seems like you have a pretty solid proof (might need some polishing, though). Is there an actual question here?

Comment: @Raphael You seem to be contradicting yourself, You put it on hold as unclear what is being asked, and you also answer his question which is only whether his reasonning is correct (and implicitly if there is more to the topic, I guess).

Comment: So, if my reasoning is correct, just answer yes XD

Comment: It may seem inconsistent but it's not; it's only that the closing reasons are not as specific as you'd like. There is no "real" question here, as in one that admits a "real" answer (in particular more than "yes" or "no"). See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/) for a related discussion. (cc @babou)

Comment: It seems Raphael's answer means yes, and I do answer that too. You are right

Comment: @babou, Raphael is saying that the answer is "yes," but there is no clear-cut question here. I.e., OP has't asked about some step of the proof if it is suspect, or if the proof is too informal, or...

Comment: The OP asked in the end whether his whole reasonning is right. It is. Actually this does not call for long answers, so it was put on hold as comments are enough. At least that is my understanding of the decision.

Comment: This applies to which PDA. I feel it applies to non deterministic PDAs in general (NDPDAs). But just want to be more precise.  Does these applies to **(1)** NDPDAs acceptance by empty stack **(2)** NDPDAs acceptance by final state **(3)** Deterministic PDAs acceptance by empty stack **(4)** DPDAs acceptance by final state. Just asked related question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85144/existence-of-one-and-two-state-pdas).